# NEXT_OFFSET records of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, pagination

I trying get the array of elements and I getting array with this code:

```
 const result = payload.map(({QUALITY, TEMPERATURE, SENSOR_READING_DATETIME, SOURCE_COMPONENT_ID, SENSOR_NAME, NEXT_OFFSET})=> ({
        TELEMATICS: {
          QUALITY,
          TEMPERATURE
        },
      SOURCE_COMPONENT_ID,
      SENSOR_NAME,
      SENSOR_READING_DATETIME,
      NEXT_OFFSET
    }));
```

in result it's looking like this:

```
{
    data": [
            {
                "TELEMATICS": {
                    "QUALITY": 91.98,
                    "TEMPERATURE": 20.5
                },
                "id": 118,
                "SENSOR_READING_DATETIME": "2021-09-24T04:53:06.801Z",
                "SOURCE_COMPONENT_ID": 1,
                "SENSOR_NAME": "TD2",
                "NEXT_OFFSET": 119
            }
            ,
            {
                "TELEMATICS": {
                    "QUALITY": 91.98,
                    "TEMPERATURE": 20.5
                },
                "id": 119,
                "SENSOR_READING_DATETIME": "2021-09-24T05:53:09.774Z",
                "SOURCE_COMPONENT_ID": 1,
                "SENSOR_NAME": "TD2",
                "NEXT_OFFSET": 120
            }
           ]
    }
```

But i trying get the NEXT_OFFSET outside the elements, and only last record of the array.

It's must be look like this example:

```
{
    data": [
            {
                "TELEMATICS": {
                    "QUALITY": 91.98,
                    "TEMPERATURE": 20.5
                },
                "id": 118,
                "SENSOR_READING_DATETIME": "2021-09-24T04:53:06.801Z",
                "SOURCE_COMPONENT_ID": 1,
                "SENSOR_NAME": "TD2"
            }
            ,
            {
                "TELEMATICS": {
                    "QUALITY": 91.98,
                    "TEMPERATURE": 20.5
                },
                "id": 119,
                "SENSOR_READING_DATETIME": "2021-09-24T05:53:09.774Z",
                "SOURCE_COMPONENT_ID": 1,
                "SENSOR_NAME": "TD2"
            }
           ]
        "NEXT_OFFSET": 120
    }
```

How i can do make it, like in the example?

Comment: There are multiple values of `NEXT_OFFSET`, one per element in the array, how do you decide which one will appear?

Comment: @EldarB. - This array have a limit of showing the records - 2000;
and  i take last record NEXT_OFFSET from this array. if there are no records - null .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate your results and add the extra field when you hit the last item. If you set the initial value of the extra property to be `null` it also takes care of your 'no results' case.

A simplified version would be like this:

```js
const payload = [
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 5, b: 6 },
  { a: 10, b: 11 }
];

const res = payload.reduce(
  (acc, { a, b }, index) =>
    index === payload.length - 1
      ? { ...acc, data: [...acc.data, a],b }
      : { ...acc, data: [...acc.data, a] },

  { data: [], b:null }
);

console.log(res);
```

For your example, if you are fetching batches of `REQUEST_COUNT` items (e.g. 2000) it could look something like this:

```
const res = payload.reduce(
  (acc, { NEXT_OFFSET, ...item }, index) => {
    const data = [...acc.data, item];
    if (index < payload.length - 1) {
      return { data };
    } else {
      const nextOffset =
        payload.length < REQUEST_COUNT
          ? { NEXT_OFFSET: null }
          : { NEXT_OFFSET 
       return {data, ...nextOffset}
    }
  },
  { data: [], NEXT_OFFSET: null }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! It's works. But how I can get NULL at NEXT_OFFSET if there are no records more ?

Comment: @NikitaAlekseev - have updated... set NEXT_OFFSET:null for the intitial value. If there are results it will get dropped.

Comment: must be like :

            {
                "TELEMATICS": {
                    "QUALITY": 91.98,
                    "TEMPERATURE": 20.5
                },
                "id": 119,
                "SENSOR_READING_DATETIME": "2021-09-24T05:53:09.774Z",
                "SOURCE_COMPONENT_ID": 1,
                "SENSOR_NAME": "TD2"
            }
           ]
        "NEXT_OFFSET": null

Comment: but if I set null at initial value, in the array with data NEXT_OFFSET will be showing wrong value. Will be better if at main array it have been showed null

Comment: @NikitaAlekseev - have updated again